# German character ß uppercased in SS

Tags: swift, uppercase, lowercase

I figured out, that "ß" is converted to "SS" when using uppercased(). But I want compare if two strings are equal without being case sensitive.
So when comparing "gruß" with "GRUß" it should be the same as well as when comparing "gru" with "Gru".
There is no uppercase "ß" in german language! Because I don't know which other characters aren't available in the corresponding languages, I could not filter all the caracters, which have no 1:1 uppercased opponent.
What can I do?

Comment: Actually, since 2008 there is an uppercase 'ß' in German: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%E1%BA%9E

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it. But I'm old and learned all the stuff in a different century! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `caseInsensitiveCompare()` instead of converting the strings
to upper or lowercase:

```
let s1 = "gruß"
let s2 = "GRUß"

let eq = s1.caseInsensitiveCompare(s2) == .orderedSame
print(eq) // true
```

This compares the strings in a case-insensitive way according to 
the Unicode standard.

There is also `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare()` which does 
a comparison according to the current locale, and

```
s1.compare(s2, options: .caseInsensitive, locale: ...)
```

for a case-insensitive comparison according to an arbitrary given
locale.

Comment: You might also consider also `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare` which will avoid issues with variations in unicode mappings.

Comment: That is interesting. I want to check if some strings are equal without being case sensitive. But to me it should be Gruß != Gruss and Gruß == gruß and Gruß != GRUSS. I want to use it as a key in a dictionary to determine quickly if that item exists.

Comment: @PeterSilie: In that case `s1.lowercased() == s2.lowercased()` should give the expected result. But note that "ß" and "SS" *are* equal when doing case-insensitive comparison.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks, that's genius! I thake that. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, "GRUß" is non-sensical in the first place for the reasons you state. You can't throw arbitrary data at a computer and expect it to process it in a sane way :-) If you have to deal with invalid input, you should probably have a preprocessing phase which cleans up crap you know about.

Having said that, this works (Swift 3.0):

```
let grusz = "GRUß"
let gruss = "GRUSS"
if grusz.compare(gruss, options: .caseInsensitive) == .orderedSame { 
   print("MATCHES") 
}
```